# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with StringBuilder

Tags: java, memory-leaks, stringbuilder, heap-memory

I am using StringBuilder class in Java to make make a large string value in a method in following way:

```
void parent() {

   int result = 0;

   while(true) {
     String s = "Some value";
     result = child(s);

     if(result == -1) {
        break;
     }
   }
}

int child(String s) {

   result = xDao.createNativeQuery(s).getResultList();

   if(result == null) {
       return -1;
   }

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()

   builder.append("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(");

   for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          builder.append(Message.Format("{0}, {0}..", result[i].val1, result[i].val2..); // This will create some big string.
   }

   // Do some operation with builder.
   dataDao.createNativeQuery(builder.toString()).executeUpdate();


   return 0;
}
```

Now say, child() is running for 100+ times, then after 70th time or so (or any higher number), I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

I have gone through this article http://mohammed-technical.blogspot.in/2010/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-with.html

As it explains how the StringBuilder just doubles it size. But in my case, I am always creating a new instance of StringBuilder inside child, then why it is throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError because of StringBuilder?

Any suggestion please?

UPDATE:

I am actually creating SQL insert statement using StringBuilder. So following operation will happen:

```
 builder.append("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(");

 While(condition) {
          builder.append(Message.Format("{0}, {0}..", var1, var2..); // This will create some big string.
 }
```

and then finally calling following lines in child() itself:

```
dataDao.createNativeQuery(builder.toString()).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What's your condition? It seems to me that your condition isn't stopping out.

Comment: Can you post stack trace of OOME?

Comment: What operations are you doing with your `StringBuilder` instance?

Comment: Could you detail `condition` and `someConditionMet`?

Comment: Most likely, without seeing your code in more detail, you are trying to build a string which is too large to fit in memory.

Comment: I have added some more details to my question regarding what I am doing with my StringBuilder instance. Can you guys understand the context now?

Comment: @Arjit: seriously I would bet dollars to donuts that your `condition` isn't stopping correctly.

Comment: Re: "why it is throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError because of StringBuilder?": What makes you think that it *is* because of your StringBuilders?

Comment: @durron597: It is breaking condition properly. As it is throwing exception in following line:
dataDao.createNativeQuery(builder.toString()).executeUpdate();

Comment: @ruakh: because in stack trace, I can see that StringBuilder class has thrown java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler such as VisualVM (http://visualvm.java.net/) to take a look at the heapdump? May be worth taking a look at.

Comment: In your posted code contains an endless loop, as condition does not change. May this be the case in the real app too?

Comment: It may be worth while adding code to track result.length. If the query got a lot more rows than expected, that could lead to a very long string.

Comment: @Herminator: Yes, I have used VisualVM, and I can see lots of instances created there of builder content.

Comment: When you use JDBC resource you need to clean them up correctly by close()ing them.  If you don't this will result in a memory leak.  The first time you aware of this leak could be when you try to build the string and there is not enough memory left.

Comment: @Arjit: can you do something straightforward like `System.out.println(builder.toString());` or an equivalent and make sure you get the correct output

Comment: @durron597: I am printing builder to my logs, string formed is proper. Also, I have placed a debug point on following line to check the builder's value.

dataDao.createNativeQuery(builder.toString()).executeUpdate();

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Did not get your point. Can you explain little more that what you are trying to point?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Your answer is likely correct. Please make it an answer so I can upvote you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use JDBC resource you need to clean them up correctly by close()ing them. If you don't this will result in a memory leak. The first time you aware of this leak could be when you try to build the string and there is not enough memory left.

> Did not get your point. Can you explain little more that what you are trying to point?

When you create a PreparedStatement or ResultSet, you have to close() them or they continue to use up memory as their Connection holds a reference to them.

The following code suggests you are creating a Statement, calling executeUpdate() on it and then discarding it.  Unfortunately this doesn't work with JDBC.

```
dataDao.createNativeQuery(builder.toString()).executeUpdate();
```

http://www.java-blog.com/correct-closing-jdbc-resources

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/closing_and_releasing_jdbc_resources.html

http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/

Comment: I am not managing connections myself in the code. I am using Spring and Hibernate/JPA to manage connections. Still there is a point of connection not getting closed properly?

Comment: AFAIK, Even with Spring you need to close your Statements.